# Why is Eclipse ignoring my Cross GCC tool prefix?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am attempting to build a sample project using the ARM Embedded GCC toolchain; for this, I am using Eclipse's internal builder.

In the settings, Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Cross Settings, Prefix is set to arm-none-eabi- and Path is set to the path of the ARM toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.7 2012q4\bin).

When I attempt to build the project, I get something that looks like this:

```
17:58:13 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project template_test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -IC:/foo/Libraries/STM32F0xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -IC:/foo/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include -IC:/foo/Libraries/CMSIS/Include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "Libraries\\STM32F0xx_StdPeriph_Driver\\src\\stm32f0xx_adc.o" "..\\Libraries\\STM32F0xx_StdPeriph_Driver\\src\\stm32f0xx_adc.c" 
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed
```

... and then an error about how gcc is not found in my path. Which, of course, it is not. There is in my path, however, an arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe, but for some reason, Eclipse is not inclined to run that one.

Why not?

I have discovered that if I change the "Command" for "Cross GCC Compiler" (Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Cross GCC Compiler -> Command) to "gc" (from "gcc") then Eclipse attempts to run "arm-none-eabi-gc" instead of "gc". I feel like that's an important clue, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Its looks like an update problem.  When I include the prefix in the command, it then tried to use the prefix twice.  I removed the prefix from the command and now it works as intended.

Comment: provide more details for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I added the path to the prefix and it seemed to work. You could also try using a short windows file path: c:/Progra~2/ ...